# Encryption similar to the one done on OSX?

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I moved on windows for some work, and I have the need to encrypt files.

Problem: Windows does not allow to simply encrypt a folder, on external drive, connect it to another Windows machine and decrypt it, like you do with OSX.

How can I do the same with Windows?

I would like to have a password prompt that allow me to access the encrypted files, independently from where the files were encrypted, just typing a password. I see that to decrypt files on another machine, I need to backup the keys from my original machine. The key should be with the files, and to access them you need to authenticate. Not sure why Windows does not use the same logic of OSX.

How can I encrypt my data and move it around between Windows installation?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: This is not a request for neither a service, learning material or seeking product. I am asking how do I encrypt something in windows, and see it on another machine without the need to copy certificates. With OSX I plug the drive, type the password and I am done; but I do not see how you do the same in Windows.